# How to export a class and one of the member methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

given the code posted below in `ClsUseStates`, i would like to `export` the method `getState()`. i investigated some posts, for example the following one:

```
class foo {
  constructor(x) {
    this.name = x
  }

  internalFooMethod(x) {
    return x + 'hello';
  }
}

const singleton = new foo();
export default singleton;

export function fooMethod(x) {
  return singleton.internalFooMethod
}
```

but i want to be able `export` the class `ClsUseStates` and the method `getState()` as well.
please let me know how to achieve that.

**note**

i know that a method can be exported as follows:

```
class ClsUseStates {
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
export const getState  = new foo()
```

but i want to be able to export the class and the method `getState`

**ClsUseStates**:

```
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

// by convention, composable function names start with "use"
export default class ClsUseStates {
    #state = ref('not-satrted');
    useStates() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.#setState('started')
        }, 1000);
      
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.#setState('processing')
        }, 2000);
      
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.#setState('successful')
        }, 3000);
    }

    #setState(state) {
        this.#setState.value = state;
    }
    getState() {
        return this.#state;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you are aiming for: Do you want `ClsUseStates` to be a singleton instance that you export? Then it's as easy as the `foo` example shows. However, if you _do not_ want `ClsUseStates` to be a singleton, the question is _which_ instance's state you want to retrieve using an exported `getState` method.

Comment: @David the class `ClsUseStates` i want to have it exported because i want to instantiate it  later. and i want to be able to export method `getState()` is it clearer now?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You'd need a "static" `getState` function like `export const getState = instance => instance.getState()` and then pass an instance of `ClsUseStates` into it after creating it via `new ClsUseStates()`, for example `getState(new ClsUseStates());`. This renders a separate `getState` function more or less useless since it is equivalent with just doing `new ClsUseStates().getState();`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @David would you please provide some code?

Comment: Have you actually read and understood what I wrote? I asked what you want to achieve so I am able to understand what you _think_ you need, but instead of answering you reply with "... provide some code?"? If you cannot explain what you need and _how it should work_ (read: how you want to use it) I am afraid I cannot help you more than I've already done.

Comment: At this point this looks like OOP for the sake of OOP. Why bother with encapsulation if you don't expose class instance? In case you're after a singleton with lazy instantiation, it's `let cls; export function getInstance() { return cls ? cls : cls = new Cls() }`

Comment: @Amrmsmb This is a class, not a composable, and a class may fall into the same trap with ref unwrapping, i.e. a value is `this.state.value` inside a class but `this.state` outside. It's unclear what's the intention. Composables aren't called outside a component, with some exceptions. If the goal is global state then it's as simple as that https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api